# how can i set the timeline to a non integer value (float value)?

Tags: timeline

I made an animation via python which sets some values on non-integers.

Now i would like to manually change these values.

how can i set the timeline on a non integer value? e.g. 12.5

I know i can change the values in the graph editor. But i would like to set the timeline and change them here:
[image]

Unfortunately i can't get these field to yellow because the keyframed value is 12.5

Comment: That's a good question... Acutally setting the _Timeline_ to a non-integer value is quite easy, in the menu under _Playback_ just at the bottom you can enable _Show_ > _Subframes_. Instead of 12 the frame value is then shown as 12.00 and you can slide the frame marker to 12.5 or enter 12.5 in the frame value. The big problem is, if you want the keyframes to show up _3D Viewport_ because it only displays full frames. Setting the _Timeline_ to 12.5, the _3D Viewport_ will show 12. Or maybe 13 if you move further. But since the keyframe is neither 12 nor 13 the values will never be shown yellow.

Comment: I've ran out of space again... Unfortunately, I can't find any Playback settings for the _3D Viewport_ allowing to show subframes. It makes sense in a way, since the viewport also shows the camera view and rendered preview etc., you would never see a subframe when you render the animation, so why should it be shown in the viewport...? Apart from setting inbetween keyframes.

Comment: thanks. You can write this as answer if you want, i will confirm that. But it is a bit sad so that i cannot adjust my values in the panel afterwards.

Comment: Maybe someone else finds a solution for that - although it helps for display in the timeline, it is no use for your actual problem because you would still need to change the values in the graph editor.